# Unable to Save Excel (xlsx) file

Tags: wine

I am unable to save Excel file. it is showing below error message.

**"Errors were detecting while saving 'C:\users\waseem\my documents\waseem saifi.xlsx'. Microsoft Office Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in new file, Click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel."**

When I am clicking on Continue button, then it is showing below error message.

**"Document not Saved.
       OK."**

After Enter, nothing happens. And I return to my unsaved file.

Please help me.
I am completely new to Ubuntu and I do lots of work in Microsoft Excel.

Regards,

Waseem Saifi

Comment: What program are you using to open the file ? You may need to convert the file to an alternate format.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to save the file to a location that starts with `C:\...`, which is used only on Windows. Ubuntu does not use such a notation for saving files.

Comment: You should give more information about the software you are using ... are you using LibreOffice with documents that were created on Windows computers? are you using Microsoft Office running with WINE on your Linux? ... 
Please tell us exactly what you are doing with which programs.
If you're creating a NEW document with the standard installed LibreOffice, you should probably save your documents in /home/<username>/Documents/<document name>.xlsx
Even if you're using MS Office with WINE, save your documents in /home/<user>/Documents.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Excel 2007 with WINE. Before Ubuntu I had windows 8 on my computer. I was tired of windows 8. So I install Ubuntu on my computer. But still I need Microsoft Excel and Access. That's why I install Microsoft Office with wine. Microsoft Office is working fine. But whenever I try to save file it shows error message which is mentioned before. I don't know why. It is still showing windows like options, when I am trying to save file. Like My Computer, Documents, C: Drive, E: Drive & Z: Drive etc. Is it installation problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your filepath looks invalid, Ubuntu doesn't have a C drive.

Do a 'Save As...' instead and save your file wherever you'd like.